# which official document or dictionary is defined for window.event.keyCode in javascript?

Tags: javascript, keyboard

Can anybody tell me which official document is defined for `window.event.keyCode`? I can't find in my JavaScript book, or via W3C. Others seem to conclude

- keycode 8 = BackSpace
- keycode 9 = Tab
- keycode 12 = Clear
- keycode 13 = Enter
- keycode 16 = Shift_L

but did't say where these come from.

Comment: May be you need http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Answer (score 3):

`event.keyCode` is deprecated. You can find the current specification regarding keyboard events at http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-KeyboardEvent

Most `keyCode` values simply come from ASCII or Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one out, scroll down to virtual key codes.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Answer (score -1):

Finally,I Got it from O'REILLY Book,JavaScript The Definitive Guide 6th Edition

```
// The legacy keyCode property of the keydown event object is not standardized
// But the following values seem to work for most browsers and OSes.
Keymap.keyCodeToKeyName = {
    // Keys with words or arrows on them
    8:"Backspace", 9:"Tab", 13:"Enter", 16:"Shift", 17:"Control", 18:"Alt",
    19:"Pause", 20:"CapsLock", 27:"Esc", 32:"Spacebar", 33:"PageUp",
    34:"PageDown", 35:"End", 36:"Home", 37:"Left", 38:"Up", 39:"Right",
    40:"Down", 45:"Insert", 46:"Del",
    // Number keys on main keyboard (not keypad)
    48:"0",49:"1",50:"2",51:"3",52:"4",53:"5",54:"6",55:"7",56:"8",57:"9",
    // Letter keys. Note that we don't distinguish upper and lower case
    65:"A", 66:"B", 67:"C", 68:"D", 69:"E", 70:"F", 71:"G", 72:"H", 73:"I",
    74:"J", 75:"K", 76:"L", 77:"M", 78:"N", 79:"O", 80:"P", 81:"Q", 82:"R",
    83:"S", 84:"T", 85:"U", 86:"V", 87:"W", 88:"X", 89:"Y", 90:"Z",
```

Thx to everyone